# Program is running even after the close button pressed

Tags: vb.net

I have a 2 form program,the first form's button click will open the second form when clicked. I tried using a .close() to hide the first form, but that ended the whole program. Then I tried using a .hide(). Now, when I click the X button in the top right of the second form, the program closes, but is still running in the background. How do I get around this?

Comment: Some code how you’re trying to call `.close()` method will be helpful for investigation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, a VB.NET application will exit when you close the startup form.  If you're hiding the startup form and closing the second form then the startup form is still open, so the app won't exit.

If you want to be able to close the first form without exiting the application then go into the project properties and set the shutdown mode to when all forms close instead of when the startup form closes.  That way, you can show your second form and then close your first form.  Closing the second form will then exit the app.

Answer (score 0):

Simply close the main `Form` from inside the second form's `FormClosed` event.

```
Sub Form2_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)
    Form1.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Me.Close()` just before the `ShowDialog()` function for the second window.

Answer (score -2):

if you want the 1st form to be visible again, add a form1.show() to the `form_closing` event of the 2nd form

if you want the program to end, add an `Application.Exit` to the form_closing event of the 2nd form

Comment: NEVER use `End`... EVER!  If you want to close the application then you can use `Application.Exit` but that's not appropriate in this case either.  Use hacks if and when they are required but don;t use them when following good practice is quick and easy, which it is in this case.